# SoapUI/Groovy - Class defined but getting NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, soapui, functional-testing

I am using Soap UI (Free version) v4.6.4. One of the test steps in my test case is to declare a class, which should be referred further in other groovy test steps; create instances and such. But to start with I tried the following in test step named `ts01`:

```
class SomeClass {
   private String name

   public SomeClass(String name) {
      this.name = name
   }

   public print() {
      log.info "SomeClass.print - " + this.name
   }
}

// After the class definition, in the same groovy script
context.project = "myproject"
context.scinst = new SomeClass("hello")
log.info context
```

When I run this test step separately, I get the following error popup:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class SomeClass
error at line: XX`

and randomly popping another error:
**java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**

When I run this test step as part of the test case, it runs but `context.scinst` is not available.

What am I missing? Why is `SomeClass` not available even though it is defined?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: I just tried this with SOAP-UI 4.5.2 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? The Groovy test step takes a script, not a class declaration.

Comment: @EJK It started working for me. I did a couple of things. I created a new project, and all the stuff piece by piece. That got me on the right track. The other thing that was, I think, the problem - I was accessing log and context in the class ctor and static initializer and it was blowing up. I removed it all. Actually that is not what I want but I need to move on for now. Thanks.

Comment: @SiKing This is what I am trying to do - I have to write an automation test engine sorta thing such that it will run a sequence of (test) steps - ws calls, response assertions etc over, say, an array of input data. So I would be defining some classes in one step in the script and later using instances of it later in another test step (script). Hope that gives an idea. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect what you are trying to do is going to be quite difficult. You might want to consider using SoapUI as a slave, and run it from JUnit: http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html

Comment: @SiKing I think I got your answers at stackoverflow and your blog posts to help me. I am new to SOAP UI and those are great source of information. Thanks.